# jQuery update doesnt work but javascript does

Tags: javascript, jquery, setvalue

I've been trying different methods of getting my page to update one input value when I select something from another.  When I try it one way using javascript it works fine, another way via jQuery it doesn't and I honestly don't understand why, could someone point out what I'm missing?

This Javascript works fine: -

```
function youPickedThis(id, num){
    var objID = "any[" + num + "].id"
    document.getElementById(objID).value = id
}
```

But this jQuery doesn't: -

```
function youPickedThis(id, num){
    var objID = "any[" + num + "].id"       
    $("#"+objID).val(id);
}
```

The objects on the being used/references are all loaded in during the page load via AJAX calls etc, is this something to do with what's causing the issue?

Thanks for any pointers, if anyone has any good links to read explaining this stuff better I'd be very appreciative! :)

Also tried this but still no dice...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                function updateHiddenInput(id, num){
                    var objID = "any[" + num + "].id";
                    $("#"+objID).val(id);
                }

            });
```

Comment: Just curious. Are you using $(document).ready()?

Comment: Why you don't use semicolons?

Comment: @Taicho - I hadn't put this function into a document ready, would that make a difference?

Comment: You should definitely give it a shot.

Comment: @Carlangueitor - semicolons we're just left out because my IDE hadn't pointed out they were required and it wasn't registering any errors in firebug so I assumed they weren't needed...

Comment: They are certainly not a must in javascript, but its good to use them for consistency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between a jQuery selector and `document.getElementById`. The second does less, so it knows that whatever you give it will be looked at as an `id`. For example:

```
var objID = "any[" + num + "].id"       
$("#"+objID).val(id);
```

What will this look for? Let's presume `num` is `1`, say:

```
$('#any[1].id').val(id);
```

This looks for an element with the `id` `#any`, an attribute `1`, and a class `id`, because the characters `[].` all have special meanings in a selector. To demonstrate this, run the following line of code in the browser console:

```
$('<div id="any" class="id" 1="foo"/>').is('#any[1].id') // returns true
```

The best way to do this selection is to do the selection with `document.getElementById`, and then wrap it in the jQuery constructor:

```
$(document.getElementById(objID)).val(id);
```

It is *possible* to escape the special characters with `\\`, but it becomes increasingly unwieldy and hard to (a) write and (b) read.

Comment: 3 correct answers all in the space of a minute so I'll have to pick the fullest for the answer but many thanks to everyone for spending the time to help my understanding!  A real lightbulb moment there! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should escape square brackect and dot

```
  var objID = "any\\[" + num + "\\]\\.id";
```

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

REFERENCE

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-jquery-wont-recognise-attribute-names-containing-square-brackets#14737000000283511

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
function youPickedThis(id, num){
    var objID = "any[" + num + "].id"       
    $("#"+objID).val(id);
}
```

This results in objID having some value like `any[3].id`, so your jQuery looks like this: `$("#any[3].id").val(id);`  jQuery interprets the .id as a class.  Escape it like this:

```
function youPickedThis(id, num){
    var objID = "any\\[" + num + "\\]\\.id"       
    $("#"+objID).val(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there are differences between jQuery selector and `document.getElementById`. As jQuery selector has to parse the string and some characters like `[`,`]` have special meaning while `document.getElementById` treats all this as part of an id. You could try escaping those special characters as mentioned by others. Here I give another solution.

You could try id attribute selector. It does something similar to `document.getElementById`

```
function youPickedThis(id, num){
    var objID = "'any[" + num + "].id'"       
    $("[id="+objID+"]").val(id);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PgpGj/)

Comment: You need a closing `]` there after `objID`.